# Cancel PrintDialog on RadRichTextBox Print Method

Tags: wpf, printing, telerik

I use telerik WPF RichTextBox and I want to print it without any user intervention.
Currently, when you call the method, the dialog opens.

```
 richTextBox.Print("Document", PrintMode.Native);
```

There is a way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution in more advanced version.

[TelerikForum](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/richtextbox/richtextbox-automatioc-print.aspx)